# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_assert_compile_was_called'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

how fix this problem. i think this the type of update error. please help to resolve this.

```
result = np.apply_along_axis(augment, axis=1, arr=X[C3]).reshape(-1, 187)
classe = np.ones(shape=(result.shape[0],), dtype=int)*3
X = np.vstack([X, result])
y = np.hstack([y, classe])
subC0 = np.random.choice(C0, 800)
subC1 = np.random.choice(C1, 800)
subC2 = np.random.choice(C2, 800)
subC3 = np.random.choice(C3, 800)
subC4 = np.random.choice(C4, 800)
X_test = np.vstack([X[subC0], X[subC1], X[subC2], X[subC3], X[subC4]])
y_test = np.hstack([y[subC0], y[subC1], y[subC2], y[subC3], y[subC4]])

X_train = np.delete(X, [subC0, subC1, subC2, subC3, subC4], axis=0)
y_train = np.delete(y, [subC0, subC1, subC2, subC3, subC4], axis=0)

X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train, random_state=0)
X_test, y_test = shuffle(X_test, y_test, random_state=0)

del X
del y
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, 2)
X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test, 2)
history = tensorflow.keras.Model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                epochs=75, 
                batch_size=batch_size, 
                verbose=2, 
                validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
                callbacks= [lrate])
```

it is working on my previous version of python. but now it is proving error of some bug, please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please post the full traceback as it's not apparent where this error is being triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code that you have provided, it looks to me that you never created a model nor compiled it? You seem to be directly calling the fit method without first creating an instance of the Model class.

There is a nice guide on the Tensorflow website that can guide you through how to create a Keras model: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate